# How to speak to a inherit class from another inherit class

Tags: c++, function, inheritance

Here to show you what I mean exactly it hard to describe without code:

```
class Object
{ 
      // attributes..
};

class Attribute
{
    public:
    void myfunc(); 
};

class Character: public Object, public Attribute
{ 

};

void main()
{
    Object* ch = new Character;
    // How can I call the myfunc() from Attribute
    // tried static_cast<Attribute*>(ch);
}
```

I only just have a Object Class pointer and i doesn't know
if it is a Character Object or another object which inherit from the
Attribute class, what i know is that the class inherit from Attribute Class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Cross casting* can only be done by dynamic_cast.

```
Object * o = new Character;
Attribute * a = dynamic_cast<Attribute*>(o);

if (!a) throw_a_fit();

a->myfunc();
```

However, for this to work you must have polymorphic base classes (they must have at least one virtual function).

Answer (score 2):

If you know that you have an object of the correct type, you can cast explicitly:

```
Object * ch = /* something that's a Character */

static_cast<Attribute *>(static_cast<Character *>(ch))->myfunc();
```

Obviously this will not be correct if the type of the most-derived object pointed to by `ch` is not a subtype of `Attribute`.

If your class hierarchy is polymorphic (i.e. has at least one virtual function in each base class that you care about), then you can use `dynamic_cast` directly at runtime and check if it succeeded, but that is a comparatively expensive operation. By contrast, the static cast does not incur *any* runtime cost at all.